# Two different approaches to structure my NoSQL database < What to choose?

Tags: nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I currently get to work with DynamoDB and I have a question regarding the structure I should choose.

I setup Twilio for being able to receive WhatsApp messages from guests in a restaurant. Guests can send their feedback directly to my Twilio WhatsApp number. I receive that feedback via webhook and save it in DynamoDB. The restaurant manager gets a Dashboard (React application) where he can see monitor the feedback. While I start with one restaurant / one WhatsApp number I will add more users / restaurants over time.

Now I have one of the following two structures in mind. With the first idea, I would always create a new item when a new message from a guest is sent to the restaurant.

With the second idea, I would (most of the time) update an existing entry. Only if the receiver / the restaurant doesn't exist yet, a new item is created. Every other message to that restaurant will just update the existing item.

Do you have any advice on what's the best way forward?

**First idea:**
PK (primary key), Created (Epoc time), Receiver/Restaurant (phone number), Sender/Guest (phone number), Body (String)

*Sample data:*

```
1, 1574290885, 4917123525993, 4916034325342, "Example Message 1"  # Restaurant McDonalds (4917123525993)
2, 1574291036, 4917123525993, 4917542358273, "Example Message 2"  # different sender (4917542358273)
3, 1574291044, 4917123525993, 4916034325342, "Example Message 3"  # same sender as pk 1 (4916034325342)
4, 1574291044, 4913423525123, 4916034325342, "Example Message 4"  # Restaurant Burger King (4913423525123)
```

**Second idea:**

```
{
    Receiver (primary key),
    Messages: {
        {
            id,
            Created,
            From,
            Body
        }
    }
}
```

*Sample data (same data as for first idea, but different structured):*

```
{
    Receiver: 4917123525993,
    Messages: {
        {
            Created: 1574290885,
            Sender: 4916034325342,
            Body: "Example Message 1"
        },
        {
            Created: 1574291036,
            Sender: 4917542358273,
            Body: "Example Message 2"
        },
        {   
            Created: 1574291044,
            Sender: 4916034325342,
            Body: "Example Message 3"
        }
    }
}

{
    Receiver: 4913423525123,
    Messages: {
        {
            Created: 1574291044,
            Sender: 4916034325342,
            Body: "Example Message 4"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read this correctly, in both approaches, the proposal is to save all messages received by a restaurant as a nested list (the `Messages` property looks like an object in the samples you've shared, but I assume it is an array since that would make more sense).

One potential problem that I foresee with this is that DynamoDB documents have a limitation on how big they can get ([400kb](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html)). Agreed this seems like a pretty large number, but you're bound to reach that limit pretty quickly if you use this application for something like a food order delivery system.

Another potential issue is that querying on nested objects is not possible in DynamoDB and the proposed structure would mostly involve table scans for any filtering, [greatly increasing operational costs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-query-scan.html).

Unlike with relational DBs, the structure of your data in document DBs is dependent heavily on the questions you want to answer most frequently. In fact, you should avoid designing your NoSQL schema unless you know what questions you want to answer, your access patterns, and your data volumes.

To come up with a data model, I will assume you want to answer the following questions with your table :

1. Get all messages received by a restaurant, ordered by timestamp (ascending / descending can be determined in the query by specifying `ScanIndexForward  = true/false`
2. Get all messages sent by a user ordered by timestamp
3. Get all messages sent by a user to a restaurant, ordered by timestamp

Consider the following record structure :

```
{
  pk : <restaurant id>,  // Partition key of the main table
  sk : "<user id>:<timestamp>",        // Synthetic (generated) range key of the main table
  messageBody : <message content>,
  timestamp: <timestamp> // Local secondary index (LSI) on this field
}
```

You insert a new record of this structure for each new message that comes into your system. This structure allows you to :

1. Efficiently query all messages received by a restaurant ID using only the partition key
2. Efficiently retrieve all messages received by a restaurant and sent by a user using `pk = <restaurant id> and begins_with(sk, <user id>)`

The LSI on timestamp allows for efficiently filtering messages based on creation time.

However, this by itself does not allow you to query all messages sent by a user (to any restaurant, or a specific restaurant). To do that we can create a global secondary index (GSI), using the table's `sk` property (containing user IDs) as the GSI's primary key, and a synthetic range key that consists of the restaurant ID and timestamp separated by a ':'.

GSI structure

```
{
  gsi_pk: <user Id>,
  gsi_sk: "<dealer Id>:<timestamp>",
  messageBody : <message content>  
}
```

`messageBody` is a non key field [projected on to the GSI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html#GSI.Projections)

The synthetic SK of the GSI helps make use of the different key matching modes that DynamoDB provides ([less than, greater than, starts with, between](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html)).

This GSI allows us to answer the following questions:

1. Get all messages by a user (using only gsi_pk)
2. Get all messages by a user, sent to a particular restaurant (ordered by timestamp) (`gsi_pk = <user Id> and begins_with(gsi_sk, <restaurant Id>`)

The system has a some duplication of data, but that is in line with one of the core ideas of DynamoDB, and most NoSQL databases. I hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Rahul, thank you for the detailed answer. The summary of the questions I want to answer are to the point. The only question I still have is about the entries `pk` and `sk` in the main table. From what I understand these are primary key and sort key. Together they can only exist once in the table, right? However, what happens if the same user (sk) sends a second message to the same restaurant (pk). Wouldn't DynamoDB block that entry as it already "exists". Only the messageBody and timestamp would differ for that case.

Comment: @JoeyCoder : You're correct, I had overlooked that. I've updated my answer to reflect the minor changes required to fix this. You can fix this by using a synthetic range key for the main table as well. The key would look like `<user id>:<timestamp>`. This helps eliminate overwriting of messages and gives you messages received by restaurant from a user sorted by timestamp without using the LSI

Comment: Thank you Rahul. I will go with that solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Storing multiple message in a single record has multiple issues

1. Size of write to db will increase as we go. (which will translate to money and response time, worst case you may end up hitting 400kb limit.)
2. Race condition between multiple writes.
3. No way to aggregate messages by user and other patterns.

And the worse part is that, I don't see any benefit of storing multiple messages together. (Other than may be I can query all of them together, which will becomes a con as size grows, like you will not be able to do get me last 10 reviews, you will always have to fetch all and then fetch last 10.)

Hence go for option where all the messages are stored differently.